# login validation on asp page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Since I'm a newbie for asp, I'm trying to take a name as input,trying to put that name in list, then check the list to find a match. I'm doing this as basics keeping the log in procedure in mind, which I will try to implement later. I have the following code:

I have made a class like this:

```
 public class Login
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The two button events are as follows:

```
List<Login> list;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    list = new List<Login>(){ 
        new Login { name = TextBox1.Text },
        new Login { name = "Badhon"}
    };

    Label1.Text = "Inserted";

}


protected void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    foreach (var s in list)
    {
        if (s.name == TextBox1.Text)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Found";
            break;
        }
        else
            Label1.Text = "Not Found";

    }

}
```

when I'm trying to insert,its working fine, but when clicking on the login button showing any error message like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Thanks for all your response, I'm going through the page life cycle to understand some very basic concept of asp.net, I think this will help me to do a bit more mature coding.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the login button you're in a different scope to when you pressed the first button, so the list is not initialised (Each time you press an ASP button you get a new state: The web is designed to be stateless).

Why not use the `asp:login` control?

Answer (score 0):

You code is not exactly what it is supposed to be. You'd better go searching for some (of the various) examples on how to hanle logins in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Each click is a new HTTP request. The list initialized in the first request is not the same with the list in the other request because each request will use its own instance of the Page object.

You need to read & understand the life cycle of a ASP.net page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: to be very honest I didn't really work in asp.net, I've worked in some winform apps. I will see the article. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

make `protected` properties to store list of logins

It should looks like this:

```
protected List<Login> LoginStore
{
     get{ return ViewState["store"] =! null ? (List<Login>)ViewState["store"] : new List<Login>; }
     set{ ViewState["store"]=value; }
}
```

You can use `Session` as well as ViewState. It will make your list doesn't disapear every time you make `PostBack`.

then in event `btnLogIn`

create `List<Login> list = LoginStore;`

then make the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

[click on here](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2008/12/user-validation-across-pages-using.html)

why do go forloop, use session variables in Global.asax, try googlin you can find many example..